How would I implement one rule multiple targets in Makefile
So this is my Makefile, I want to do it differently, not just all: ...
I'm trying to compile and link a kernel driver
PLATFORM := x64
CONFIGURATION := debug
PROJECT_NAME := Necrobyte

BIN_PATH := "bin\\$(PLATFORM)\\$(CONFIGURATION)\\"
OUT_PATH := "build\\$(PLATFORM)\\$(CONFIGURATION)\\"

# ++ COMPILE ++

SRC_FILES := $(wildcard *.c)

CC := "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe"
CFLAGS := /c /Ibin\$(PLATFORM)\$(CONFIGURATION)\ /Zi /nologo /W4 /WX /diagnostics:column /Od /Oi /Oy- /D _WIN64 /D _AMD64_ /D AMD64 \
            /D DEPRECATE_DDK_FUNCTIONS=1 /D MSC_NOOPT /D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 /D WINVER=0x0A00 /D WINNT=1 \
            /D NTDDI_VERSION=0xA00000C /D DBG=1 /D KMDF_VERSION_MAJOR=1 /D KMDF_VERSION_MINOR=15 /GF /Gm- /Zp8 \
            /GS /guard:cf /Gy /fp:precise /Qspectre /Zc:wchar_t- /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR- /Fo"bin\$(PLATFORM)\$(CONFIGURATION)\\"\
            /external:W4 /Gz /wd4748 /wd4603 /wd4627 /wd4986 /wd4987 \
            /FC /errorReport:queue /kernel -cbstring -d2epilogunwind /d1import_no_registry /d2AllowCompatibleILVersions \
            /d2Zi+
            
CINCLUDE := /FI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\warning.h"\
            /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include"\
            /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\km"\
            /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt"\
            /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared"

# -- LINK --

SRC_OBJ := $(patsubst %.c, $(BIN_PATH)%.obj, $(SRC_FILES))

LNK := "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe"
LFLAGS := /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\ihxd\Desktop\Necrobyte\build\x64\debug\$(PROJECT_NAME).sys"\
            /VERSION:"10.0" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /WX /SECTION:"INIT,d"\
            /NODEFAULTLIB /MANIFEST:NO /DEBUG\
            /PDB:"$(BIN_PATH)$(PROJECT_NAME).pdb"\
            /SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE,"10.00" /Driver /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /ENTRY:"FxDriverEntry" /RELEASE\
            /IMPLIB:"$(BIN_PATH)$(PROJECT_NAME).lib"\
            /MERGE:"_TEXT=.text;_PAGE=PAGE" /MACHINE:X64 /PROFILE /guard:cf /kernel\
            /IGNORE:4198,4010,4037,4039,4065,4070,4078,4087,4089,4221,4108,4088,4218,4235\
            /osversion:10.0 /pdbcompress /debugtype:pdata\
            

LINCLUDE := "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\km\x64\netio.lib"\
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\km\x64\BufferOverflowFastFailK.lib"\
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\km\x64\ntoskrnl.lib"\
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\km\x64\hal.lib"\
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\km\x64\wmilib.lib"\
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\wdf\kmdf\x64\1.15\WdfLdr.lib"\
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\wdf\kmdf\x64\1.15\WdfDriverEntry.lib"

# ** TEST SIGN **

SGN := "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /ph /fd "sha256" /sha1 "9606C369B02FF06D537D40268DCCE5DB4D1E5FF7"

all:
    $(CC) $(CINCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC_FILES)
    $(LNK) $(LFLAGS) $(LINCLUDE) $(SRC_OBJ)
    $(SGN) $(OUT_PATH)$(PROJECT_NAME).sys

This is what I tried.
$(OUT_PATH): $(SRC_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CINCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC_FILES)

But I get the error "Multiple targets. STOP"
I've tried different methods but none of them worked no matter what I tried.

Which make is this for?  Considering that you're on Windows, which shell? Please copy & paste the actual error message and any relevant preceding lines into the question.

You are saying that the OUT_PATH, which is a directory, depends on all the source files.  That won't work correctly because the modification time of a directory is computed differently than a file: it's updated whenever the directory changes (files are created, deleted, or renamed).  As John asks, which version of make are you using?  If GNU Make, you should not use backslashes in targets or prerequisites.  You have to use forward slashes.  Also you should not use quotes in the names of targets or prerequisites.

@JohnBollinger I've managed to get it working, there's one more issue, when I get all the .c files (I add src\ before %.c and *.c and I get linker error that no files were specified, any idea why

That sounds like a separate question.

Maybe consider a more modern build system like CMake https://cmake.org/
